# Which do I select - Windows Azure or Amazon EC2 - for hosting unmanaged C++ code?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, azure

We have a server solution written entirely in unmanaged Visual C++. It contains complicated methods for really heavy data processing.

The whole thing contains millions lines of code, so rewritning it all in some other language is not an option. We could write some extra code or make isolated changes, but rewriting everything is out of the question.

Now we'd like to put it on a cloud. Which platform do we choose - Amazon EC2 or Windows Azure - and why?

Comment: Tricky question, could be considered argumentative or community or both. Shouldn't it be asked at serverfault?

Comment: BTW: I wouldn't choose either. Using a classical cloud solution that doesn't lock you in into their technology is probably better. Rackspace (not their default cloud solution) and Elastichosts are among companies I know that offer normal root access plus fully flexible server space, but many others exist.

Comment: @Abel: No, its a question about which plaform to choose for development. How does it belong to serverfault any more than choise between different languages?

Comment: Good point. I looked at it from a server-perspective, but you're right, it certainly might matter to developers.

Comment: There is no such thing as "unmanaged C++".  There is only C++, and a bastardized language Microsoft created.

Comment: managed c++ makes managed/native interop easier than on any other platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it require Administrative rights on the box (e.g. writing to registry, changing box configuration, installing components, etc)? If it does, you can't use Windows Azure today.

If it doesn't require admin privileges then the other things you need to think about are:

- What is the architecture? How does it interact with the world? Files? databases?
- What dependencies you have?
- What is the usage pattern (burst? continuous?)
- What would be the cost based on usage and the pricing of both offerings?

That would hopefully give you some more datapoints to help you make a decision.

Comment: This may have been accurate at the time, but today, you can get full administrative access to azure instances.  RDP access is available, as well as the ability to install components and such by script at deployment time.

Comment: That is correct. Much has changed (for the better!) in the last 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

That depends largely on how you think about costs, future value of the platforms, etc... Azure is still in its very early stages. There are definitely more people using EC2 today. I would recommend computing the costs between the two platforms as a starting point given your estimated usage. Do you want to use features that one platform has over the other? How does your app benchmark between the two platforms? Do you want to take advantage of spot pricing?

In either case I would recommend adding a thin shim layer to abstract you from whichever you choose and enable you to move in the future if you need to.

This is like windows vs. linux....there are no universal right answers, only opinions.